# Qt version 5.6.3 later are boot slower than 5.6.3

Tags: qt

I created a new  Qt Widget Application project in Qt Creator and started it at 5.6.3, 5.9.7 and 5.12.0, respectively. I found that the boot time of 5.9.7 and 5.12.0 was tens of milliseconds slower than that of 5.6.3. Somebody know why?

Test Env : Windows 10/vs2015

Here is the  [testcase](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16OcDycxfA6vJ-YN7KaZwrYseDsFajRQG)

Comment: It would be great if you provide the test that you have implemented

Comment: more information like the compiler version, platform, test procedure shall be helpful...

Comment: testcase has been submitted.

Comment: @王堃澎 What are the times for each version?

Comment: 5.6.3   :    93ms
5.9.7   :   167ms
5.12.0 ：179ms